# R function which transforms data adds new column depending on counted grouped rows

Tags: r, group-by, transform, rows

I am new in R, so maybe anyone could help me.
I have dataset like this

| ID | Date | Revenue | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022.01.01 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022.02.01 | 11 | 21 |
| 1 | 2022.03.01 | 12 | 22 |
| 2 | 2022.01.01 | 13 | 33 |
| 2 | 2022.02.01 | 14 | 41 |
| 2 | 2022.03.01 | 15 | 51 |
| 2 | 2022.04.01 | 16 | 61 |

I need to transform this dataset, with group_by(ID). Also is important how much rows there is by group.
My transformed data must look like that:

| ID | Revenue4 | Revenue3 | Revenue2 | Revenue1 | Sales4 | Sales3 | Sales2 | Sales1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | 12 | 11 | 10 | - | 22 | 21 | 20 |
| 2 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 13 | 61 | 51 | 41 | 33 |

I need to do this by some function, because I have a lot of rows with different ID's and about 40 columns.

Thank You!

Comment: Pleases share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: I corrected the data view. Now looks more understandable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a column containing the row number within each group, and then use `pivot_wider` using the row number in the new column names, combined with sales and revenue.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
              names_from = rn,
              values_from = c("Revenue", "Sales"))
```

**Output**

```
     ID Revenue_1 Revenue_2 Revenue_3 Revenue_4 Sales_1 Sales_2 Sales_3 Sales_4
  <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1        10        11        12        NA      20      21      22      NA
2     2        13        14        15        16      33      41      51      61
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as the other answer, but with `data.table`:

```
##
#   In future provide this using dput(...)
#
df <- read.table(text="ID   Date    Revenue     Sales
1   2022.01.01  10  20
1   2022.02.01  11  21
1   2022.03.01  12  22
2   2022.01.01  13  33
2   2022.02.01  14  41
2   2022.03.01  15  51
2   2022.04.01  16  61", header=TRUE)
##
#   you start here
#
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, N:=seq(.N), by=.(ID)] |> dcast(ID~N, value.var = c('Revenue', 'Sales'), sep="")
##    ID Revenue1 Revenue2 Revenue3 Revenue4 Sales1 Sales2 Sales3 Sales4
## 1:  1       10       11       12       NA     20     21     22     NA
## 2:  2       13       14       15       16     33     41     51     61
```